# jQuery not posting - (jQuery - ColdFusion)

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have a small function that deletes records from my database using ColdFusion 9 and jQuery

The function exists in 3 other locations and it is identical and functioning as it supposed to but it seems to have an error with this page.

**Html Form code**

```
<form name="devRatingCat" method="post" action="" >
    <table  class="table table-bordered table-striped" >
        <tr>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Category Name</th>
        </tr>
        <cfloop query="categories">
            <tr>
                <td><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="mark" value="#recID#"></td>
                <td>#recID#</td>
                <td>#categoryname#</td>
            </tr>
        </cfloop>
    </table>
    <hr />
    <div class="pull-left">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onClick="dlteCatR(mark);" >Delete</button>      
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
function dlteCatR(field)
{               
    var $srt = $(field);
    var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this Category? \n You will not be able to revert this change!")
    if(r==true){
        for(i=0; i<$srt.length; i++){   
            if($srt[i].checked == true){
                var url="surveyAdmin.cfc?wsdl&method=deleteRateCat&recId="+$srt[i].value;
                $.post(url);
            }
        }
        window.location.reload();
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

**surveyAdmin.cfc method**

```
<cffunction name="deleteRateCat" access="remote" returntype="void" output="no"  hint="Delete Rating Categories.">
    <cfargument name="recID" type="string" required="true" hint="The id of the rating category to delete.">
    <cfquery datasource="#dsn#">
        delete from rating_categories
        where id = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#arguments.recID#">
    </cfquery>
</cffunction>
```

I'm using firebug to track the calls but it doesn't give me any good explanation as to why it is not working.

Also, when I copy the link in firebug and run it by itself in a browser the transaction is happening as it should

Comment: The problem is most likely here: `window.location.reload();` you should wait until all the post requests are done first. Also, you should make a mass-delete method in your cfc so that you can delete multiple records with 1 request rather than sending multiple at once. that or a helper method that iterates over an array of argument combination that sends the arguments 1 set at a time into the target method.

Comment: @KevinB the `window.location.reload();` happens after all the post requests are finished.

Comment: @KevinB after I removed it completely the function is working

Comment: Why would you use an AJAX call to do the delete...but then do a  page refresh? Seems kind of counter productive.

Comment: @ScottStroz I'm new to the ajax/jquery thing so if you have a suggestion please feel free to help out :)

Comment: @Geo *"the `window.location.reload();` happens after all the post requests are finished."* No, it doesn't. that's the root of your problem.

Comment: @KevinB I got that after I moved it around a bit. I thought that by having it outside of the loop it would run after all of the requests are over

Comment: The requests are asynchronous, $.post(...) just sends the request. If you don't wait for the request to complete before refreshing the page, it wont... complete. the for loop sends all of the requests at once, at the same time, then you attempted to reload before they were all complete. You can solve this with deferred objects, but you really should instead create a mass-delete method so that you can do it with a single $.post.

Comment: @KevinB you should write up an answer for this so that others finding this question in the future can see it easier than in these comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$.post()` sends an asynchronous request. If you reload the page before that request is complete, the request will be aborted.

In your case, you are sending out n requests all at once in the for loop, and then immediately reloading the page (with this line `window.location.reload();`) before any of them have time to complete. To solve this, you can either consolidate them all into one `$.post` request and use the success callback, or you can store each promise object returned from `$.post()` in an array and pass it to `$.when`.

I suggest using the first solution of consolidating all of the requests into one request and using the success callback, however that will require you to either modify your current cfc method to accept multiple records to delete at once, or to create a new cfc method that can handle it.

One way would be to have your method capable of handling a list of id's rather than a single id.

```
<cffunction name="deleteRateCat" access="remote" returntype="void" output="no"  hint="Delete Rating Categories.">
    <cfargument name="recID" type="string" required="true" hint="The id of the rating category to delete.">
    <cfquery datasource="#dsn#">
        delete from rating_categories
        where id in (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#ListAppend(arguments.recID, 0)#" list="yes">)
    </cfquery>
</cffunction>
```

And the js to go with it:

```
function dlteCatR(field){               
    var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this Category? \n You will not be able to revert this change!")
    if(r==true){
        var recIdList = $("[name=" + field + "]:checked").map(function(){
            return this.value;
        }).get().join(",");
        var url="surveyAdmin.cfc?wsdl&method=deleteRateCat&recId="+recIdList;
        $.post(url).done(function(){
            window.location.reload();
        });        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin. As I said earlier I am relatively new to jQuery/AJAX so 'IF' you can provide some code examples I would appreciate it. I am not looking for a copy/paste answer but rather a rough draft that I can play with and learn more.

Comment: @Geo I'll add that while i'm here.

Comment: It isn't fool proof since you're passing the parameter as a GET parameters and there's a pretty restrictive limit on the maximum length of the querystring, but it should work for most cases.

Comment: Was happy to learn about the list argument to cfqueryparam, i've never used it before this. That will definitely make some of my existing code cleaner.

Comment: I can't thank you enough! I have some cleaning up to do and a lot more to learn!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42609/discussion-between-geo-and-kevin-b)

Comment: Instead of doing a reload (which kind of makes doing the AJAX call kind of fruitless, no?), you could simply remove the element you are deleting from the DOM when the AJAX request is finished. Performing some process via AJAX and then reloading the page when it is done is kind of redundant and adds an extra HTTP request for every item you want to delete.